# Ionic local storage store sensitive data for private app

Tags: xss, account-security, sensitive-data-exposure, local-storage

I'm new to the ionic framework and have some basics of it and currently I'm developing a private app for my family only that store some sensitive information in the localstorage. I used some crypto libraries to encrypt the whole data to prevent anyone reading it directly.

The app does not call any external API, links to any external network and website, and it does not connect to any server host since it is just for our own use only.

The question is, is there any vulnerability for anyone to attack my private app and get the data from localstorage? I've read some article saying that localstorage is either attack by physically getting the device or by XSS.

Comment: I am not very familiar with Ionic, but is the localstorage you are referring to the browser's localstorage?

Comment: Yes like browser's localstorage but everything is done internally without connecting to any external services. So i assume it is highly no chances for people to retrieve my localstorage data.